# Looking for Clearlooks for Gtk-3.0 or something similar

Tags: themes, gtk

I am looking for a theme that replicates the look of the classic Clearlooks theme from Gtk2 or something that at least looks similar, i.e. something basic, with rounded corners that doesn't overdo it with distracting color gradients. Having the arrows on the scrollbar would also be nice. Suggestions?

[image: Clearlooks Screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this theme :

[Clearlooks-Phenix](http://www.jpfleury.net/en/software/clearlooks-phenix.php)

Comment: Thanks, works great so far. To install it under XFCE I needed to use:`ln -s ~/.themes/clearlooks-phenix-master/gtk-3.0/ ~/.config/gtk-3.0`

Comment: Thanks! Clearlooks-Phenix for Gtk 2 and Gtk 3, plus Cleanlooks for KDE make a great desktop integration for people like me, running all kinds of apps with different toolkits.

Answer (score 1):

Try the Sonar (3.2) or Elements themes in the WebUpd8 themes PPA.

Comment: Yeah. Elements from the same source is also very lo-fi, however all of these new themes crowd your `~/.xsession-errors` with errors and warnings.

Comment: @aquaherd: is there any theme that does not?